# css3 technique for jelly input animation

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

What's the general idea/technique behind doing something like this in CSS3? Would it be possible?

(I'm talking about the line, not the label, which I know how to do)

[image]

I found it [here](http://www.materialup.com/posts/jelly-input-field)

Comment: Learn the CSS animations then you can do it yourself ;)

Comment: @Muhammad A similar comment can be applied to ALL the questions!  Learn XYZ and you can do it !

Comment: @Muhammad it may or may not be possible to do this exact effect and so I'm asking those who are already experts on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this can be done using SVG animations.
You can use a library called [SnapSVG](http://snapsvg.io/).
Take a look at some of these amazing fluid SVG animations [Elastic SVG Elements](https://tympanus.net/Development/ElasticSVGElements/hamburger.html) created by Mary Lou.

Answer (score 0):

This Is Not Exactly What You Want. But Take A Look:

```css
body,
html {
  background: #111;
}
#ib {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 40px;
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #09f;
  outline: none;
}
#ib:focus {
  -webkit-animation: anim 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.080, 0.805, 0.930, 0.220);
}
@-webkit-keyframes anim {
  0% {
    border-radius: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    border-radius: 150px/10px;
  }
  100% {
    border-radius: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="ib" placeholder="Type Something">
```